# can someone help me play this video using videojs player

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I tried playing the video using html5 video tag and video.js player, but i am not able to play the video and the video has an mp4 format.

the video can be downloaded from https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwvTwArK2QWBVVZhbnAtMjZlWlU

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.2.7/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 -->
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="test.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
      <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
  </video>

  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.2.7/video.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting an error message :- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrujV.png)

Comment: Can you tell us which video-codec is present in the MP4?  And which browser is being being used for the test?

Answer (score -1):

Try using single-quotes with data-setup as it is expected to contain `JSON`.

```
data-setup='{}'
```